# Unexpected auto sorting by spark2-submit on python dictionary

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

An unexpected sorting behavior on Python dict while using 'spark2-submit'.

[tmp.py]

```
d = {
    'name': 'stackoverflow',
    'email': 'atack@xxx.com',
    'zip': '628888',
}
print(d)
```

**Expected:**

```
{
    'name': 'stackoverflow',
    'email': 'atack@xxx.com',
    'zip': '628888',
}
```

**Actual:**

**`> -bash-4.1$ spark2-submit tmp.py`**

```
{'name': 'stackoverflow', 'zip': '628888', 'email': 'atack@xxx.com'}
19/08/08 09:33:35 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/08/08 09:33:35 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-9bb6bd82-ba2c-4715-b27a-6fdc41d3297b
-bash-4.1$
```

I'm in the situation of not being able to use 'python or python3 tmp.py' command. It's a big story. Please ignore this. Python or Python3 way, it's working perfectly. I want to make it to work through **`spark2-submit`** way.

Doubts, based on actual results:

1. Why it's sorting automatically. (From my understanding to increase the performance in Spark side, may apply this logic. If once ignore.)
2. If once sorting, it doesn't use 'key' wise (If once then `email` should comes at top)
3. If once it's using 'value' wise then `628888` should comes at top.

Wants to know, in which manner it's applying the sorting functionality and how to stop this auto sorting. I need the order in the same way what we are giving as input.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In python, `dict` keys have no defined sort order. You can use an OrderedDict to maintain key order: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Example:

```
import collections

orderedDict = collections.OrderedDict()
orderedDict['name'] = 'stackoverflow'
orderedDict['email'] = 'atack@xxx.com'
orderedDict['zip'] = '628888'

print(orderedDict)
```

**Note:** 
As of Python3.7+, dicts do in fact keep their key insertion order. 
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html